# References on semigroup actions

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, semigroups-and-monoids, group-actions, topological-dynamics

I posted this question on Math Stack Exchange about 10 days ago, but received no answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4843881/1223994).
I would like to ask for references on semigroup actions on metric spaces from a topological point of view. Thanks

Comment: You might be interested in work by Gray & Kambites on semigroup actions on metric spaces; a good place to start is [this article, giving a Schwarz-Milnor lemma](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S021819671100687X) for some semigroup actions.

Comment: Out of curiosity would a semi-group G acting on a metric space X be a functor of semi-categories between the semi-category G and the category of metric spaces?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what systems you had in mind, but my go-to reference for this would be the book "Dynamics of Evolutionary Equations" by George R. Sell and Yuncheng You, specifically "Chapter 2. Dynamical Systems: Basic Theory". The goal there is to develop a theory of limit sets and global attractors for semiflows on Banach spaces.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this volume emphasizes the generality of the space (Banach spaces rather than, say, finite-dimensional manifolds), but covers only the case when the semigroup is $\mathbb{R}^+$.